# Jquery .post() clarification

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, sqlite

Hey all,
I know this question has been asked a million times before but I just can't seem to convert the answers into my personal project.  I have a selector on my page that needs to send an AJAX query to my database and retrieve the results and print them under the selector.  Thank you to anyone who can clarify what needs to be done for this to work.

Here is the php file called "view.php" minus the query I make to the database.

```
$depView = $_POST['depView'];

foreach($result as $entry){
echo  '<div>' . $entry['department']. $entry['CRN']. ' ' . $entry['title'] . ' ' . $entry['addDate'] . '</div>';
}
```

Here is my Javascript thus far:

```
function getProps(data){
        $.post("view.php", {depView: data}, html)

        }
```

Here is my selector:

```
<select onchange="getProps(value);" name="depView">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="CSC">CSC</option>
        <option value="MAT">MAT</option>
        </select></br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<select name="depView" id="depView">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="CSC">CSC</option>
  <option value="MAT">MAT</option>
</select><br />
<div id="ajaxResults"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// on DOM load
$(function () {

  $('#depView').change(function () {
    $.post('view.php',
       { depView: $(this).val() },
       function (data) {
         $('#ajaxResults').html(data);
       },
       'html'
       );
  });

});

</script>
```

Comment: How do I call this function when I change the selector?

Comment: `$('#depView').change` calls view.php every time You change the selector.

Comment: For added fun, you could throw some simple animation in so users are more aware of what happened:               `$('#ajaxResults').slideUp('fast', function () {
               $(this).html(data).slideDown('slow'); });`

Answer (score 1):

You must use a the callback function to retrieve data after the successfull request.

It could be something like that :

```
$.post('view.php', {depView: data}, function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
});
```

Just edit the part in the "function(data)" to do what you want with the retrieved data.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace your `$.post` code with:

```
$.post("view.php",{depView:data},
   function(msg) {
     alert("Data Loaded: " + msg);
   },"html")
```

`msg` contains the result of executing view.php

You could replace `alert("Data Loaded: " + msg);` with `$('selector').html(msg)` .
The last param `html` is opotional.jQuery indentifies the type of data send by view.php .

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, or at least it doesn't output the result

Comment: A little mistake.Try now ,please.

Comment: Replacing alert with $('selector').html(msg) will make it appear in the window instead of an alert?

Comment: No.You should change selector with some div id/class ,etc.Like css.#someid is div with id="someid". After  `</select></br>` add `<div id="qresults"></div>` and You should replace alert with `$('#qresults').html(msg);`